# Inheritance and Private Methods

Tags: java, inheritance

Given the following block of code:

```
public class Trial {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        B obj = new B();
        obj.doMethod(); #prints "From A".
    }
}

class A {
    private void method(){System.out.print("from A");}
    public void doMethod(){method();}
}

class B extends A {
    public void method(){System.out.print("from B");}
    public void doMethod(){super.doMethod();}
}
```

It turns out that the method() from class A is invoked. Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

You explicitly implement it that way. `super` calls method from base class which is `A`

```
public void doMethod(){super.doMethod();}
```

So the method chaining is like this:

```
B.doMethod() -> A.doMethod() -> A.method() -> "from A"
```

Comment: Sorry typo. Meant to ask why method() from class A was invoked.

Answer (score 2):

I think your question is if in `class A` `private void method(){System.out.print("from A");}` is private then why is printing "from A" in `class B`.

Answer is very simple you can't call `method()` of A class form any other class .But you can call it with object of its own.

when you calls `super.doMethod();` then its function of super and `method()` is its own method so it can call it.

Answer (score 0):

Because, see below:

```
class B extends A {
    public void method(){System.out.print("from B");}
    public void doMethod(){super.doMethod();}
}
```

Here in Class B's doMethod() you're invoiking Class A's doMethod() using super.doMethod(). So obviously it's printing Class A's doMethod().

Answer (score 0):

You call the doMethod with **super** keyword. It's means it will call parent implementation
More on [super keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your code gives simple object creation (B obj = new B();) and a call using super. Super is used like other people mentioned for parent class. Things could have been different if you try something like (A obj = new B();), which is more interesting.

Answer (score 0):

method() in class A is private and private methods can't be overriden. And when overriding it's better to use @Override annotion.

```
class B extends A {

    @Override
    public void method(){System.out.print("from B");} // Compile error
}
```

A similar thing happens, if you change the method to a static method.

```
class A {
    public static void method(){System.out.print("from A");}
}

class B extends A {
    public static  void method(){System.out.print("from B");}
}
```